# How to add full page background image in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to add a background image to an entire welcome page in NextJS and it's just not working. Before, I was having trouble with the fact that NextJS seems to render every component inside a master component that becomes an html div with a class of "__next". Therefore, every time I try and add a background image that takes the full page, it is only as big as the "__next" div and is cut off. I tried using NextJS' image component, but now it doesn't even load the image and just displays the alt text. Can anyone tell me how to fix the following code?

```js
import React from "react";
import styles from "/styles/WelcomePage.module.css";
import Card from "/Components/Card";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

function WelcomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>Welcome to Class Chooser</h1>
        <button type="button">
          <Link href="/ClassSearch"> Class Search </Link>
        </button>
        <Image
          src="/images/graduates.jpg"
          alt="Cartoon graduates jump with happiness"
          quality="100"
          layout="fill"
        />
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default WelcomePage;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a background image simply do it via CSS:

```css
.card {
  background-image: url("/images/graduates.jpg");
}
```

Comment: I did  ```.card {background-image: url("/images/graduates.jpg");
}
``` before and it wasn't working.

Comment: Any other clue on why not? Is it working on other elements or on a stackblitz? Does it work with a Google Images URL? If it does, the problem lies on the src

Answer (score 1):

When you add layout="fill" to Image you need to wraper Image component in parent element and assing postion property to parent (relative, absolute, ...).

Wrap your Image inside a parent div, and make your parent position fixed

```
<div className="bg-image-wrapper">
 <Image
   src="/images/graduates.jpg"
   alt="Cartoon graduates jump with happiness"
   quality="100"
   layout="fill"
   />
</div>
```

In css

```
.bg-image-wrapper {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

make your parent component (Card) **position relative** and add below properties to next-image.

```
layout="fill"
objectFit="cover"
```

position relative should be there for which you need to apply image as a background.

Comment: I included layout and objectFit in the image component and switched the Card component to position relative and it unfortunately still doesn't display the image.

Comment: I fixed it, the src attribute doesn't take paths for static content you have to import it